# Popup Editor with Dropdownlist Object issue

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm using a custom popup editor with add new record for DropdownList Object, but it cant update object in new record only show undefined.

Here is my current code at http://jsfiddle.net/Lights/C3KcV/

```
columns: [{ field:"permRule", title: "Permission Name", width: "250px", editor: permRuleEditor
                            ,template: function(record)
                            {
                                if(record.permRule != null) return record.permRule.name
                            }
                        }]

function permRuleEditor(container, options) {
                    console.log(options)
                    $('<input required data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField:"name",
                        dataSource:listPerm
                    });
                }
```

Sorry for my bad English and Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the "dataValueField" in your drop down list.

It should be more like this:

```
.kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField:"name",
    dataValueField:"value",
    dataSource:listPerm
});
```

Comment: if i want to invoke grid's popup editor from my own button, how can i do it? thanks